Why do we test on the t distribution rather than any other asymptotically normal distribution?
Following on from this question, where the answer states there isn't anything special about the t distribution for non-normally distributed data, I would like to know why the t distribution is used.
The answer given to my linked question is that the t distribution is more conservative than the z distribution. However the t distribution isn't conservative for any underlying distribution (I think?), so why not choose something even more conservative that is asymptotically normal? (we have infinite possibilities). Obviously if we go too far our tests will be too weak, so perhaps the best way to phrase the question is:
How do we decide how conservative a distribution to test on for small sample sizes of non-normally distributed data? and why is it generally agreed that the t distribution best balances this tradeoff?

The argument for using a $t$ test with non-normally distributed data is that the test is typically on the sample mean of the data (or the difference of sample means), and that may be approximately normally distributed even when the individual observations are not, but with rescaling by the (non-symmetrically approximately chi-distributed) sample standard error leading approximately to the $t$ distribution.  So then it comes down to how small the sample is, and how close are the approximations to the normal distribution and chi distribution.

@Henry yes, but it's also approximately normally distributed, and approximately any other asymptotically normal distribution. Apparently the t-test tends to be a closer approximation most of the time, but not all of the time, and there is no theoretical reason why another distribution might not approximate the distribution of the t-statistic well more often than the t-statistic does.

It's not a question of choosing one distribution or another based on one's appetite for conservatism. It's just that under the null hypothesis, if the standard deviation of the data is not known but must be estimated, the test statistic follows a $t$ distribution. This is a mathematical theorem. (Of course, the applicability of the conditions is always up for discussion.) See COOLSerdash's comment at the original thread. Details and a proof are typically given in textbooks on mathematical statistics.

The t statistic only follows the t distribution for normally distributed data, and I am specifically talking about non-normal data. E.g. for a discrete distribution, the t statistic will follow a discrete distribution, so it can't be t-distributed, though the discrete distribution will start to look more like a t- (or normal) distribution as sample size increases.
